# Missing "aud" claim in access token

Tags: identityserver4

For unknown reason to me the "aud" claim is not present in access token (it is present in id token though).

Once access token is being sent to the API i get the following error:

> Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10214: Audience
> validation failed. Audiences: 'empty'. Did not match:
> validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'productconfigurationapi' or
> validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

I know i can turn off audience validation and everything works then but i don't get why "aud" is not part of the access token.

Here's my IS4 configuration:

the client:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Spa",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "productconfigurationapi"
                },
                RequireConsent = false
            }
```

the api resource:

```
            new ApiResource("productconfigurationapi")
            {
                UserClaims =
                {
                    JwtClaimTypes.Audience
                }
            }
```

the API Scope:

```
    return new List<ApiScope>
    {
        new ApiScope("productconfigurationapi")
    };
```

and here's how IS4 is configured within its host application:

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should tie the ApiScope to the ApiResource by setting the Scopes property:

```
var api = new ApiResource("productconfigurationapi")
{
    UserClaims =
    {
       //...optional user claims...
    },
    Scopes = new List<string>
    {
        "productconfigurationapi"
    },
};
```

To complement this answer, I write a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: it looks like adding `JwtClaimTypes.Audience` UserClaim explicitly is excessive. It's enough to assign a scope to the client and ApiResource.

Comment: UserClaims is just an example.

Comment: Sure, but it's misleading as it is. When you wish to include an example claim, you would better to use `UserClaims = {"ExampleClaimType"}`, otherwise just skip adding. Everybody knows, SO is used for copy-pasting day by day, without too much thinking, so... :)

Comment: I polished the answer :-)