# User.Claims is empty after upgrading from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, jwt, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-5.0

After upgrading from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to version 5, `context.User.Claims` is empty in

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
```

in

```
public class MyRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
```

I'm using the `Authorization` header with a bearer token with JWT. I can see that header being set correctly when looking at the `HttpContext.Request.Headers` but it doesn't seem to be parsed.

This is set up on a Grpc Service with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

With ASP.NET Core 3.1, it worked fine. I went through the [official migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) but their references regarding authorisation were only for Azure Active Directory.

I'm using IdentityServer4 which is hosted within that ASP.NET Core app as a middleware (`app.UseIdentityServer();`)

What did I forget to modify to get ASP.NET Core to parse the authorisation header correctly?

**Update:**

I checked it in more details and noticed that it's failing because it can't verify the audience (`aud`) - and yes on the newly created tokens the audience is missing (the old tokens had the audience). Also I noticed that a custom scope, which I was adding in

```
public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
```

inside my custom

```
public class ProfileService : ProfileService<ApplicationUser>
```

is also missing after the update. This is how the IdentityServer is configured:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, AppIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(AuthResources.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(AuthResources.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(TestClientsRequired
        ? ClientsForTesting.GetTestClients()
        : Clients.GetDefaultClients());
```

Comment: Is any part of the auth token parsed correctly? Is this a new token, or was it created prior to the migration?

Comment: It's in my development environment, so it's nearly created and no token is parsed. Although, I can verify that the token looks correctly with jwt.io. The user object is pretty empty except for config values so I'd assume that nothing is parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After figuring out that the issue might have been due to a missing audience (`aud`) I looked further and found [Missing "aud" claim in access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930426/missing-aud-claim-in-access-token) - the answer was, to explicitly add the audience as a claim and also set the scope one more time, and it worked.

For me this looks the following way:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    yield return ApiResourceBuilder
        .IdentityServerJwt(MyWebApiResource)
        .AllowAllClients()
        .Build()
        .AddUserClaims()
        .AddScopes(); // <- this is new
}

private static T AddUserClaims<T>(this T resource)
    where T : Resource
{
    resource.UserClaims.Add(Constants.CustomClaimTypes.MyRoles);
    resource.UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Audience); // <- this is new

    return resource;
}

// this whole method is new ->
private static T AddScopes<T>(this T resource)
    where T : ApiResource
{
    resource.Scopes.Add(MyWebApiResource);

    return resource;
}
```

Comment: I guess you skipped Identityserver v4 in your migration, and jumped from 3 to 5. [They changed a lot in 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4592).

Comment: I kept using identityserver4 - i used it with asp.net core 3.1 and now with asp.net 5 - that's the weird thing, it might be that my configuration before was wrong but somehow worked - I don't know

Comment: No, Identityserver4 is just a short name for "Identityserver for .Net Core" and it has its internal versioning. Versions 3.x and 4.x target asp.net core 3 and 5.x is for .net 5.

Comment: ah that's what you meant, because I used to use identityserver3 in a previous project and this one started with identityserver4 from the beginning that's why I was confused. thx for the hint, I'll double check that issue to see if I have to upgrade anything else