# Audience is empty in generated jwt token

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I am trying to use OpenIddict as an authorization server and I managed to produce a token, however I have no idea how to put the "aud" claim in the token.

I could of course manually add it to the created ClaimsPrincipal, but I'm wondering if there is a way for that like in IdentityServer. In IdentityServer you could declare api resources, and for those resources, you could declare scopes. If a scope of an API resource was requested, the name of the api resource was included as an audience.

Is there a way to tell OpenIddict that if a scope is requested, include a special audience, or it has to be implemented manually?

Comment: Does this SO thread help resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930426/missing-aud-claim-in-access-token

Answer (score 5):

You can attach a list of resources to a scope when creating it via the scope manager:

```cs
await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictScopeDescriptor
{
    DisplayName = "Demo API access",
    DisplayNames =
    {
        [CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")] = "Accès à l'API de démo"
    },
    Name = "demo_api",
    Resources =
    {
        "resource_server"
    }
});
```

Then, use `ListResourcesAsync(scopes)` to list all the resources associated with the specified scopes. E.g:

```cs
principal.SetResources(await _scopeManager.ListResourcesAsync(principal.GetScopes()).ToListAsync());
```

Comment: when trying to implement new OpenIddictScopeDescriptor i get an error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictScopeDescriptor' to type 'OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore.Models.OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreApplication'.'

Comment: this error caused because you are using IOpenIddictApplicationManager manager, use this one:
var scopeManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictScopeManager>();